# How should make it so that cheese goes up

Tags: javascript, html

So how would I make so that the variable cheese goes up. I know it is mostly likely the defining of the variable cheese every time that the JS is activated, but I have no idea how to about. Can you give some help?

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="picture.png" height="35%" width="35%" onmouseup="Cheese();">
  <p id="cheese_count"></p>
  <script>
    cheese = 0;
    Cheese = function() {
      cheese++;
    }
    document.getElementById("cheese_count").innerHTML = "Cheese: " + Cheese; <
    /script <
    /body> <
    /html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`++cheese` will increment `cheese` and return the new value, so in your function, you can simply have this:

```js
document.getElementById("cheese_count").innerHTML = "Cheese: " + (++cheese);
```

I changed the function name from `Cheese` to `incCheese` in order to avoid ambiguity with the variable `cheese`. Also, I put "Cheese: 0" in the paragraph element so that it shows that way at the start.

Side note: `width="35%" height="35%"` won't work. Instead, use CSS.

```html
<html>

<body>
  <img src="https://placehold.it/1" style="width: 10%; height: 10%;" onmouseup="incCheese()">
  <!--changed to 35% to 10% to fit in the snippet ^^           ^^ -->
  <p id="cheese_count">Cheese: 0</p>
  <script>
    cheese = 0;

    function incCheese() {
      document.getElementById("cheese_count").innerHTML = "Cheese: " + (++cheese);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```